# Trying to print mapped data but function is returning nothing

Tags: python, numpy, mapreduce, mapper

```
import numpy as np
with open("/Users/myname/Downloads/names/yob1880.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
for line in text:
    print (line)
def mapper():
    for lines in line:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        name, sex, number = data
        print ("{0}\t{1}".format(name, number))
```

dataset has comma separated values of name, sex and number. dataset is taken from here: https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/names.zip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMghV.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post text or code as image, it will be more difficult for people to help You.

Comment: in your mapper `line` contain your last line which is probably empty, remove the first loop

Comment: why you `split("\t")` instead of `split(",")` ...

Comment: If I remove the first loop I will not get all the lines from my dataset.

Comment: @bella please do not edit your question substantially after it has received one or more answers, as the newly-edited question may invalidate existing answers. If you have a new question, ask it as a new Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

with open("/Users/myname/Downloads/names/yob1880.txt","r") as f:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f)
    def mapper():
        for line in csv_file:
            name, sex, number = line
            print ("{0}\t{1}".format(name, number))
    mapper()
```

The csv module helps out quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of

```
for lines in line:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        name, sex, number = data
        print ("{0}\t{1}".format(name, number))
```

You should actually use the single line (which in your case is called `lines` or rephrase your variables).

Thus, think about this here:

```
for line in text:
        data = line.strip().split(',')
```

Do you see the difference? `lines` and `line`?

---

Also, reading the comments and the provided files, you should `split(',')`.

Or even better, use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, that comes with a csv reader.

Comment: I already replaced split(',') and changed line to lines. Still its not returning anything.